# Yii2 image dimension validation

Tags: php, image, yii, yii2, yii-cactiverecord

This validation line doesn't work. i could upload images in any dimension.

```
['image', 'image', 'minWidth' => 250, 'maxWidth' => 250,'minHeight' => 250, 'maxHeight' => 250],
```

in the controller, i use.

```
 $image = UploadedFile::getInstance($this, 'image');
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the last line as far as I can see.
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/tutorial-core-validators.md#yiivalidatorsimagevalidatorimage-

But you're declaring rules for the `image` attribute twice - one as a file, and one as a image. The image validator extends from the file validator, so it inherits all its properties.

> **Image Validator (docs):**
>
> This validator checks if the input value represents a valid image file. It extends from the file validator and thus inherits all its properties. Besides, it supports the following additional properties specific for image validation purpose:

Try combining it in to one rule, and see if that helps.

```
[
     'image', 
     'image', 
     'minWidth' => 250, 
     'maxWidth' => 250,
     'minHeight' => 250, 
     'maxHeight' => 250, 
     'extensions' => 'jpg, gif, png', 
     'maxSize' => 1024 * 1024 * 2
],
```

**Edit:**
And you need to save the image in the `$model`, like `$model->image`for it to be validated through the model validation rules if you're in the controller.

Here is a good example:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-file-upload.html

Comment: i tried to combine it and as mentioned. it doesnt still work. instead its just getting uploaded without validation. i doubt if image validator is working correctly because i could even upload .csv file with this

Comment: Just saw something, updating answer